# detect suspect

Tags: sql-server, database

How To detect the suspect database in SQL server2000 With Script Or Program ?

Comment: Thats some blasphemous ms sql slang, but, honestly, it got me thinking of FBI and some kind of "database of suspects" the moment I've seen the question.

Answer (score 2):

the status column in master.dbo.sysdatabases will have the suspect bit set which is 256 for the database.  in which case this will return a result:

```
select  * from sysdatabases where status&256 = 256
```